# How to have a numberpad in a textfield of an alert controller [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to call an alert controller which has a textfield. But I'd like to show immediately the numberpad since the user should input numbers only.
I tried with the following but it does not work.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Rating", message: "Rate this!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

  let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in })

  let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    self.updateRating(textField.text)
  })

  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) in }

  alert.addAction(cancelAction)
  alert.addAction(saveAction)

  self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 34):

Found it on my own! It might be useful for someone else.

```
alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { textField in
    textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
})
```

Comment: This should now be `UIKeyboardType.numberPad`

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3:

```
alert.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
}
```